# Lookup and merge using lists in python

Tags: python, performance

Given 2 lists of same length ,the operation I want to perform is lookup in second list and merge the result in original list. However, the key and value of lookup changes.

```
# Input

data = ["A", "ReplaceMe", "ReplaceMe", "A", "ReplaceMe", "C"]
replace_values = ["Version1", "", "", "Version2", "", ""]


# Expected output
['A', 'Version1', 'Version1', 'A', 'Version2', 'C']


def replace_elements(dataset, replacements):
    for j, i in enumerate(dataset):
        if i == "A":
            replace_by = replacements[j]
        if i == "ReplaceMe":
            dataset[j] = replace_by
    return dataset
```

My current implementation gets the job done, but has O(n) complexity. Can I use `dict` to get this done in a faster way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the job with `pandas`. It does a forward fill on the `replace_values`, then replaces the ReplaceMe's with the value on the same row in `replace_values` with `np.where`:

```
import pandas as pd

data = ["A", "ReplaceMe", "ReplaceMe", "A", "ReplaceMe", "C"]
replace_values = ["Version1", "", "", "Version2", "", ""]

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(data,replace_values), columns=['data', 'replace_values']).replace('', None).ffill()
df['data'] = np.where(df['data'] == 'ReplaceMe', df['replace_values'], df['data'])
df['data'].tolist()
```

Output:

```
['A', 'Version1', 'Version1', 'A', 'Version2', 'C']
```

Comment: Brilliant, for including `pandas` in solution.

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot go beyond the O(n) implementation, despite the use of data structures for the look-up anyway you must do a single scan of the data in input.

This is a one-liner version, using the walrus operator, but I don't expect that this goes faster:

```
[current if dt=='ReplaceMe' else  dt for (dt,rp) in zip(data,replace_values) if (current := (rp if dt=='A' else current))]
```

Comment: Thanks for input, have infrastructure restrictions , so still on python2.6